# Docker build not working- permission denied

Tags: docker, fedora

I am trying to build my docker images but failing with permission denied. 
Docker service is up an running.
Do I need to be root/have sudo access to build images?

`[jack@localhost work]$ docker build -t my-app .`

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.26/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&buildbinds=null&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=my-app&ulimits=null: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

```
[jack@localhost work]$ service docker status
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you need to be root or be in the docker group with the current default configuration. Being able to manage Docker is effectively being root.

Comment: @Ry- my user already added in docker group [jack@localhost work]$ cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:975:jack

Comment: @jack.hamper you need to logout and restart docker service or just run: newgrp docker